# How to draw a image on exact coordinates on a android compose canvas?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I looked in the the auto-complete list to find something, but wasn't successful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some docs on that: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/draw/modifiers

Here is a code example:

```
@Composable
fun Drawing() {
    val image = ImageBitmap(30, 30)
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.drawBehind {
        drawImage(image, topLeft = Offset(x = 100f, y = 200f))
    }) {
        // Draw scope
    }
}
```

Or to draw an image in the draw scope, here are some [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/drawscope/DrawScope#drawImage(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ImageBitmap,androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset,kotlin.Float,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.DrawStyle,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ColorFilter,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.BlendMode)) and an example:

```
fun drawImage(
    image: ImageBitmap,
    topLeft: Offset = Offset.Zero,
    ...
): Unit
```